# Happy with 18.04, except for suspend behaviour. Should I update to 18.10>>>19.04

Tags: upgrade, suspend

I'm new to Ubuntu, and have installed the 18.04 on my laptop. After some tinkering, it works fine except for suspend, which is successful in 90% of times. These 10% failure bugs me, since I can't move from one place to the next and be sure that the system will wake-up from suspend. During work this can be annoying for me and for people waiting for my laptop to re-boot.

Is it realistic to expect that suspend will work better in 18.10 or 19.04? Otherwise I won't go through the trouble of upgrading yet.

Lenovo Thinkpad E485, Ryzen 3 2200U Vega 3, Bios updated to 1.52

Comment: You can certainly try other releases in live session to test for the intended behavior. If they work better, why not? But keep in mind 18.04 is LTS with 5 years support and the newer ones aren't, the next LTS release will be 20.04. And a LTS release also gets kernel updates.

Comment: No don't upgrade the distribution just to try out a newer kernel. Install the newer kernel directly in 10 minutes and keep the older ones around for backup. A distribution update takes hours and there is no going back if something breaks. You have to do a fresh install of your current version.

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely. If that is all stick with LTS if you can not be bothered with what a not-LTS offers.

Mind that IF 18.10 or 19.04 do get a fix for this it will trickle down to 18.04. But the problem is likely on the hardware/bios level. The log files in `/var/log/` might help identifying what went wrong. And it might be worth checking what you have as bios and see if there are updates for it.

I went for another solution that keeps me away from suspend and hibernate. I have not used those 2 for several years now: I put a SSD as main disk in my machine: booting into the desktop takes roughly 7 seconds. That is quick enough for me as I mainly use mine during a commute from and to work.

Comment: The boot time from SSD is fantastic, but it's also about having files and browser tabs open.

Comment: My 5% suspend failure ends up rebooting anyway so shutting down saves nothing and causes forced login 95% of time where resuming would have worked. The important thing about suspend is always save your work as if you were going to shut down. +1 for SSD promotion and freeing the people from HDD enslavement :)

Comment: @QuoraFeans true but you are supposed to save your work before suspend. Maybe it is possible to mimic this with a script: dump current open session info into a cache on disk and reopen it on boot.

Comment: @Rinzwind: how do you dump an open session? BTW, it's not just about saving changes, but about having things at hand, like pdf X open at page 31, browser tabs with news about topic T.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/ for instance.